# Looking to subtract data in 1 column

Tags: sql-server

So far I tried subtracting with max and min which is fine unless there is a  third      record found with a 0 in it. I also tried within a case statement to look for wither forecast or worked and set 1 of them to negative but that didn't work either. I need the difference grouped by employee,rectype,datebegin and dateend. 0 recs can get in there

```
     Table

     Employee RecType DateBegin DateEnd Hours


     Sample

     123,Forecast,1/1/2014,1/8/2014,5
     123,Forecast,1/9/2014,1/16/2014,7
     123,Forecast,1/9/2014,1/16/2014,0
     123,Worked,1/1/2014,1/8/2014,5
     123,Worked,1/9/2014,1/16/2014,4


     Output I'm looking for

     123,Difference,1/1/2014,1/8/2014,0
     123,Difference,1/9/2014,1/16/2014,3
```

Comment: What query are you trying? Can you explain the output a little further, I'm not understanding

Comment: how do you have 2 forecasts for the same timeframe/ID?

Comment: I tried these so far MAX(hours) - MIN(hours) AS 'Difference'
    SUM(CASE WHEN 'hours type' = 'Worked' THEN 0 - hours  ELSE hours END)

Comment: Please add the entire query to the question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will have matching records for Employee ,RecType , DateBegin, DateEnd
for Forecast and Worked you could get your result by:

```
Set DateFormat  mdy
declare @a table(Employee int ,RecType varchar(20), DateBegin DateTime, DateEnd dateTime, Hours float)

insert into @a 
select 123,'Forecast','1/1/2014','1/8/2014',5
UNION
select 123,'Forecast','1/9/2014','1/16/2014',7
UNION
select 123,'Forecast','1/9/2014','1/16/2014',0
UNION
select 123,'Worked','1/1/2014','1/8/2014',5
UNION
select 123,'Worked','1/9/2014','1/16/2014',4

Select x.Employee,x.DateBegin,x.DateEnd,x.Hours-y.Hours as Hours
from
(
Select Employee,DateBegin,DateEnd,SUM(Hours) as  Hours
from @a where RecType='Forecast'
Group by Employee,DateBegin,DateEnd
) x
JOIN
(
Select Employee,DateBegin,DateEnd,SUM(Hours) as  Hours
from @a where RecType='Worked'
Group by Employee,DateBegin,DateEnd
) y
on x.Employee=y.Employee and x.DateBegin=y.DateBegin and x.DateEnd=y.DateEnd
```

Comment: Here is a sql fiddle of a working example of this if it helps: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/649c9/6